# Is there a term for using color to describe taste or flavor, instead of using the actual flavor?

Tags: colloquialisms, food, sense-verbs

For example, if someone says "this tastes purple" instead of saying it tastes like grape, or if asked what flavor of Gatorade you prefer you answer with, "blue".

It also seems common with candy and artificial flavors (or flavors perceived as artificial), and I'm wondering if there's specifically a name or term for this type of substitution.

I'm specifically talking about uses that are *not* due to synesthesia or some other kind of disorder or medical condition.

Comment: It’s called *baby-talk*. -  not specific to colors and taste though.

Comment: I assume your’re not talking about some form of *Synesthesia*

Comment: ***Synesthesitic synecdoche***, duh.

Comment: @Jim funnily enough, a friend is the origin of this question, and _synesthesia_ was my snarky answer to it. But this question is about cases where that is definitely not the cause. Although some instances of this are deliberate attempts at baby talk, other times it's not really for that kind of effect, I think. I'll edit to add some clarification.

Comment: @briantist - When daughter was about 2 we went to Sea World and got cotton candy.  I asked her what flavor hers was.  She said, “Pink”

Comment: @Jim not at all synesthesia. adjectives for vision (colors) and touch (soft) are ... of themselves, But other senses use nouns or verbs in pure simile: there's no good 'perfumy' word, you just say that something smells like perfume.  Some languages do the same for vision: in [Pirahã](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3) 'red' is really ['like blood'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3_language#Color_terms). What's the word for this? It's not [parataxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis) but is associated with such seemingly oversimplified grammar.

Comment: @Mitch - Right.  I wasn’t suggesting It was.  I just wanted to verify with OP that It wasn’t what he was thinking of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is perhaps not specific enough but ... I think this is a category of metonymy.

> **metonymy**.
>   : a figure of speech consisting of the use of the name of one thing for that of another of which it is an attribute or with which it is associated (such as "crown" in "lands belonging to the crown")
>   [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metonymy)

Comment: Metonymy applies when the usage is established. "This tastes purple" is just nonsense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That doesn't make any sense. How can a usage become established if it isn't already? Metonymy applies equally well to original phrases and to clichés.

Comment: @Caleb 'How can a usage become established if it isn't already?' implies that the English language never changes, which is obviously nonsense. But trying to add respectability to nonsense / baby-talk by calling a DIY string a 'word' or saying 'He sounded indigo' is an example of a particular figure of speech is disingenuous and hardly English **usage**. Chomsky's  famous 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' was intended to illustrate grammatical nonsense. 'This tastes purple' violates the Gricean maxim of quantity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It sounds like you're saying that "this tastes purple" is nonsense because nobody says that. (OK, it doesn't *really* sound that way -- I obviously can't hear you, but sometimes people use one word when they really mean another...) *Somebody* was the first to say "I've got wheels" or "we need boots on the ground," and it wasn't nonsense when they did, even that very first time.

Comment: @Caleb 'Colorless green ideas sleep furiously' is still the nonsense it was intended to be, though many more examples of it being used have occurred than of 'This tastes purple' intended seriously.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if someone says "this tastes purple" instead of saying it tastes like grape, or if asked what flavor of Gatorade you prefer you answer with, "blue".

I don't think we have a term that refers specifically to substituting a color for a flavor and that's not related to synesthesia. It doesn't seem to be something that's common practice.

I think k1eran's answer of *metonymy* is the right one if the speaker is substituting *purple* for *grape*. Another possibility is that the speaker is using *irony*: since artificial grape flavor often doesn't taste like *real* grapes, using the color that's usually associated with the flavor is way to show that you know the flavor is "grape" but not truly grape.

In the latter example, though, "blue" is very nearly the actual name of a flavor — Cool Blue is the name of one Gatorade flavor:

[image: Gatorade Cool Blue]

As well, the speaker could be indicating a preference for all of the several Gatorade flavors that are colored blue.

Flavors often have a strong connection to specific colors, and vice versa. Processed foods like candy or sports drinks are often given colors that tell the consumer what flavor to expect, so describing a flavor in terms of its associated color isn't so strange. Conversely, we have lots of colors that are named for flavored things: *orange*, *grape*, *cherry*, *lemonade*, *espresso*, *rosemary*, *cabernet*, and *mint* are just a few words that can be either a flavor or a color.

Comment: Hm, blue gatorade was not a good example then. I don't drink gatorade but it's something I thought I heard, maybe it was about vitamin water flavors or some other drink.

Comment: Perhaps you heard it correctly, and it only sounded odd to you because you're not well versed in Gatorade flavors?

Comment: It was a joke, something along the lines of `anyone who refers to gatorade flavors by name and not color is 100% a cop`. Searching on twitter, I see that this is a popular sentiment: https://twitter.com/search?q=flavors%20colors%20cop

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered two kinds of this - the "baby talk" referred to in comments (sorry I can't remember you're username and posting on my phone - will edit later, if I remember), and a slightly disparaging way of saying "this has a faint or indistinct flavour I associate with food or drink of this colour".

The latter I'd probably call **sarcasm**.